# What does this stamp mean?

Tags: passport-stamps, barcelona

Can someone tell me what this stamp means?
[image: '']

Comment: The double line usually means that whatever stamp it has been applied to has been cancelled. Judging by where you first posted this picture, I'd say you passed border control at Barcelona on your way to leave, and then for some reason, didn't get on the plane. Perhaps you could explain where and how you got the stamp.

Comment: i just pass border in barcelona but i lost my flight

Answer (score 4):

It means that after you missed your flight, the border officers cancelled your exit from the Schengen area (rather than readmitting you).  One possible reason for doing this would be if you had a single-entry or dual-entry visa, with all of the entries used up.